# Rearrange information in several lines to just one

Tags: sql

I've got a table that was created in a way that any person with more than one car end up appearing in more than one line:

mytable:

```
 name       car
 -----      -----
 Joe        Ford    
 Alex       Ferrari        
 Alex       Audi    
 Jimmy      Fiat
```

Is there any way to create a SQL query that returns that table rearranged to only one person per line, and concatenated cars?

wanted table:

```
 name       car
 -----      -----
 Joe        Ford        
 Alex       FerrariAudi                  
 Jimmy      Fiat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`. Concatenation of car types depends on the database you use. In [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html) you could write

```
SELECT name, string_agg(car, '') AS car FROM mytable GROUP BY name
```